# Google Map not showing

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im trying to place a google map on my website but its not working. Here is the code that I have. Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong. Thanks

```
<head>
<title>Environment Impact</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<script>src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY=TRUE"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
          var california = new google.maps.LatLng(-122.23354, 37.48787);
          var myOptions = {
            center: california,
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
        }
</script>
 </head>
 <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:800px; height:600px; border:1px solid #000;"></div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong formatting and possibly bad parameters:

```
<script>src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY=TRUE"></script>
```

should be something like:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=TRUE"></script>
```

making sure the `MY_API_KEY` is replaced by your Google Map API key, or simply ignore this parameter if you don't need it.
Not sure you want the `sensor` to `TRUE`, I just guessed since you had an orphan `=TRUE` parameter

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I didn't realize this silly mistake. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Your script line should be

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>`

Also `california` is not a valid center, you need a latLng like:

`center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.19533058280067, -120.234375),`

Answer (score 2):

Wrong

```
<script>src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY=TRUE"></script>
```

Right

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=true"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY=TRUE"></script>
```

That's not right at all

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=false"></script>
```

would be closer, if that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

yes the script tag needs to be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

and set sensor=false

Answer (score 0):

By the way, the parameter `sensor` in the Url has to be set to true or false depending on the app. If the the app uses a sensor like a gps transmitter to find out the user-location, it is `true`. More info [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=de)

The key as a parameter is only necessary if the website/app has no [Google](https://developers.google.com/console/help/?hl=de#UsingKeys) oauth access token yet and will not lead to any verification of the user as opposed to the oauth token .